# mysql wont work easyphp xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, easyphp

I'm trying to create local web server with EasyPHP or XAMPP. When I run XAMPP or EasyPHP first time, everything works correctly. In PhpMyAdmin I create a database and do what I need. But when I'm trying to run programs next time, MySQL won't work. 
I've found only the one way to make MySQL work again - delete ibdata1 file but by doing this I loose my MySQL data.

Sorry for my English and thank you for your answers!

P.S.
There is my MySQL error log file.

```
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1814 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
> removed in future releases, together with the option
> innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Warning] InnoDB: The log sequence number in the ibdata files is higher than the log sequence number in the
> ib_logfiles! Are you sure you are using the right ib_logfiles to start
> up the database. Log sequence number in the ib_logfiles is 1600607,
> logsequence numbers stamped to ibdata file headers are between 1600617
> and 1600617.
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1600617 and 1600617 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence
> number 1600607 in the ib_logfiles!
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>     2013-11-23 14:46:58 1092 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace
> mysql/slave_relay_log_info uses space ID: 3 at filepath:
> .\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace
> wordpress/wp_terms which uses space ID: 3 at filepath:
> .\wordpress\wp_terms.ibd
>     InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\wordpress\wp_terms.ibd
>     InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>     InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
>     InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
>     InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
>     InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
>     InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
>     InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
>     InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
>     InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
>     InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
>     InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: Got the ~ same error : Could not find a valid tablespace file for: ...
Restarting mysql does the trick. Using EasyPHP 14.1 VC 11

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of the CAUSE of this issue but here is how I fixed it.

I've disabled innodb file per table by adding `innodb_file_per_table = OFF` to my MySQL configuration file.

Then for each damaged table:

`[ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for '<base>/<table>'`

I create a folder `<base>` in the `data` folder of my mysql installation. And inside an empty file named `<table>.frm`.

Then connect on your database and do `DROP TABLE <base>.<table>`.

The `DROP` should be successful, even if the error log shows an error :

`InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"<base>"."<table>"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 255.`

[EDIT] If you have a lot of tables in a base, you can also create only the folder `<base>` in the `data/` directory, and issue `DROP DATABASE <base>`.

/!\You will lose any table that is not corrupted